# cheerio.filter()? what is the reason why the this code did't run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

This is part of my code:

```
request(main_url, function(error, response, html) {                      // two parameters: an URL and a callback
            if(!error) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                console.log("begin");
                $('.test').filter(function() {
                                  console.log("in");
                });
                console.log("end");

            }
    });
```

The console displays:
**begin
end**

It is really weird, i did a test to check whether the object of whose class is test exists or not, result is that it exists.

So i dont know **why** it pass line 4 directly to line 8?

Comment: " i did a test to check whether the object of whose class is test exists or not", how?

Comment: @Vohuman if($('.test')){do something}

Comment: That is always true since `$('.test')` returns an _object_ and an _object_ is considered a _truthy_ value in JavaScript. You should check the `.length` property of the object. Also note that it doesn't "pass line 4 directly to line 8". The collection seems to be empty and the `.filter` callback is not executed!

Comment: @Vohuman oh my god, thank you, I learned a new thing, i always thought if( $('.test') ) is right for months!!  I am sorry because i was new in javascript. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Vohuman Yes, callback, omg, i ignored this, too. Thank you for your patience for me, the fresher!

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @Vohuman by the way, can you possible to recommend some websites for understanding node.js(callback)? I think i really need to learn more, i didn't the real principle of node.js

Comment: Callback functions are not specific to Node.js. A callback function is one of the key parts of JavaScript programming in general. This link might help: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/.

Comment: Here is a better post regarding JavaScript callbacks: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: @Vohuman Sorry to apply late, thank you for your response, i will check it now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `request` returns the response as a binary `Buffer`, instead of a decoded `String`.

You need to first *convert* `html` into a string before passing it to cheerio, using `toString`:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html.toString());
```

Comment: I dont think it is this problem, because i tried to use it in other places, it is the problem of my collection is null, so callback is not excited. But i am really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Even if your collection *did* contain a `.test`, your callback would still not execute, until you use `toString` as mentioned here.

Comment: Or at least on my setup, I needed to do this change for your code to work. Yours could be different, but it's still an error in your code if you don't use `toString`.